# Hangman game background image possibly inefficient

Tags: java, performance, functional-programming, homework, hangman

I'm making a Hangman game and it seems that my code doesn't provide me much freedom with using layouts. I added an image to my `JFrame` then I added a `JPanel` to my image which I'm using for all the `JLabel`s and `JTextField`s but it seems to me that it's inefficient because in order to change the layout of my `JTextField`s or `JLabel`s I have to change the layout of my image which messes up the entire looks of the game.

How can I make this code more efficient and give myself more freedom to change the layouts of my `JLabel`s and `JTextField`s without messing everything up?

```
/*PACKAGE DECLARATION*/
package Game;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;


/************************
 * GAME MECHANICS CLASS *
 * **********************/
public class GameStructure {

    /* INSTANCE DECLARATIONS */
    private String []wordList = {"computer","java","activity","alaska","appearance","article",
           "automobile","basket","birthday","canada","central","character","chicken","chosen",
           "cutting","daily","darkness","diagram","disappear","driving","effort","establish","exact",
           "establishment","fifteen","football","foreign","frequently","frighten","function","gradually",
           "hurried","identity","importance","impossible","invented","italian","journey","lincoln",
           "london","massage","minerals","outer","paint","particles","personal","physical","progress",
           "quarter","recognise","replace","rhythm","situation","slightly","steady","stepped",
           "strike","successful","sudden","terrible","traffic","unusual","volume","yesterday"};
    private int []length = new int [64];
    private JTextField tf;//text field instance variable (used)
    private JLabel jl2;//label instance variable (used)
    private JLabel jl3;//label instance (working on)
    private String letter;


    /*****************
     * LENGTH METHOD *
     * ***************/
    public void length(){

        jl3 = new JLabel();

        int j = 0;
        for(j = 0; j<64; j++) {

            length[j] = wordList[j].length();//gets length of words in wordList
        }//end for

        int l = 0;
        String line = "";
        //create line first then put into .setText
        for(int m = 0; m<length[l]; m++) {

            line += "__ ";
            l++;
        }//end for
        jl3.setText(line);

        }//end length method


    /*****************
     * WINDOW METHOD *
     * ***************/
    public void window() {

    LoadImageApp i = new LoadImageApp();//calling image class

    JFrame gameFrame = new JFrame();//declaration
    JPanel jp = new JPanel();
    //JPanel jp2 = new JPanel();//jpanel for blanks
    JLabel jl = new JLabel("Enter a Letter:");//prompt with label

    jl.setFont(new Font("Rockwell", Font.PLAIN, 20));//set font

    tf = new JTextField(1);//length of text field by character
    jl2 = new JLabel("Letters Used:    ");

    tf.setFont(new Font("Rockwell", Font.PLAIN, 20));//set font
    jl2.setFont(new Font("Rockwell", Font.PLAIN, 20));//set font

    jp.add(jl);//add label to panel
    jp.add(tf);//add text field to panel
    jp.add(jl2);//add letters used

    gameFrame.add(i); //adds background image to window
    i.add(jp); // adds panel containing label to background image panel

    gameFrame.setTitle("Hangman");//title of frame window
    gameFrame.setSize(850, 600);//sets size of frame
    gameFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);//exit when 'x' button pressed
    gameFrame.setIconImage(new ImageIcon("Hangman-Game-grey.png").getImage());//set the frame icon to an image loaded from a file
    gameFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);//window centered
    gameFrame.setResizable(false);//user can not resize window
    gameFrame.setVisible(true);//display frame

  }//end window method


    /*********************
     * USER INPUT METHOD *
     * *******************/
    public void userInput() {

        tf.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {//when enter key pressed

            JTextField tf = (JTextField)e.getSource();

            letter = tf.getText();
            jl2.setText(jl2.getText() + letter + " ");//sets jlabel text to users entered letter

            }//end actionPerformed method

        });

    }//end userInput method

}//end GameMechanics class



/*PACKAGE DECLARATION*/
package Game;


/***********************
 * IMPORT DECLARATIONS *
 * *********************/
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


/***************
 * IMAGE CLASS *
 * *************/
public class LoadImageApp extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private ImageIcon image;


        /***********************
         * PAINT IMAGE METHOD *
         * *********************/
        public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {

            //setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            super.paintComponent(g);
            image = new ImageIcon("hangman.png");//image name & type
            image.paintIcon(this, g, 270, 20);

        }//end paintComponent method

}//end LoadImageApp class

/*PACKAGE DECLARATION*/
package Game;


/*******************
 * GAME MAIN CLASS *
 * *****************/
public class GameMain {


    /***************
     * MAIN METHOD *
     * *************/
    public static void main (String []args) {

        GameStructure game = new GameStructure();//declaration
        game.length();
        game.window();
        game.userInput();

    }//end main method

}//end GameMain class
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to do two things:

1. Split your image into multiple pieces that will be loaded into different panels.
2. Use appropriate layout managers when adding components so that you can control how components are arranged.  [Layout Manager Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Since I can't see your image, I can't make specific suggestions, but remember that you can layer multiple Layout Managers together.